# How to check version number of lnd?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

New lnd version came out recently, but I'm not sure which version I'm running. How can you check?

Answer (score 2):

`$ lnd --version` did the trick.

Output should contain the version plus commit hash

`lnd version 0.5.0-beta commit=f4305097e1638f6f8958dfa9eec941d8bf80246e`

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `$ lnd version` to see info about the version number, and the network you’re connected to.